# How to override JSON data displayed on table?

Tags: html, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make a simple review app of game of thrones. This contains two input fields one for the seasons and another for the episode. I am trying to parse JSON-data into a table with two columns. First column would contain the picture and second would contain the review. The picture changes on changes made on the input field but I couldn't override the data on the second column. It just keeps on appending.

Being beginner, and new to StackOverflow I have low reputation. So I can't post picture. Else it would have been much clear.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#btn-got-load').on('click', function () {
    var $season = $('#txt-season').val();
    var $episode = $('#txt-episode').val();
     var $url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Game%20of%20Thrones&Season=" + $season + "&Episode=" + $episode + "";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : $url,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    if (key == "Poster") {
                        $("#image-here").html("<img src='" + value + "'>");
                    }
                    $("#review-here").append("<li>" +key +" : "+ value + "</li>");
                });
                $("#review-here").append( "<br/>");
            }
        });
     });
```

```html
<h1><u>Game of Thrones review</u></h1>
<label>Season (1-5) : </label> <input type="text" id="txt-season" value="1"/>
<label>Episode (1-10) : </label> <input type="text" id="txt-episode" value="1" />
<input type="button" id="btn-got-load" value="review"/>
<div id="container-div">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="image-here"></span>
            </td>

            <td>               
                <ul id="review-here"></ul>                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear it before you start adding the lines:

```
        success: function (data) {
            $("#review-here").html(""); // clear it first
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                if (key == "Poster") {
                    $("#image-here").html("<img src='" + value + "'>");
                }
                $("#review-here").append("<li>" +key +" : "+ value + "</li>");
            });
            $("#review-here").append( "<br/>");
        }
```